# Angular/Bootstrap - Navbar with toggleable sidebar

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, navbar

Im trying to build a progressive web-app with Angular and Bootstrap. The most challenging part is to implement a navbar that looks good on the web and on the mobile view. For the most part I'm pretty happy with my implementation so far. See Link on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-235xeh)

**But** now I am trying to toggle the navbar as a Sidebar, that opens up from the right to the left. Additionally the sidebar should push the content (Placeholder-Text) to the left. This could be kind of tough, because that perhaps means modifying some Bootstrap classes. Maybe some of you have a solution for this. Currently my navbar toggles the links underneath.

#### html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img alt="logo" src="https://..." width="40px" height="auto">
        My Brand
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mr-md-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="javascript:void(0)">Stories</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mr-md-3">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span>
            <img class="rounded" src="https://..." alt="user" width="35" height="35">
            <span class="d-none d-lg-inline">&nbsp; Tommy</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <div class="img-container" (click)="notificationsViewed = true">
            <img alt="notifications" src="https://..." width="35">
            <span [hidden]="notificationsViewed" class="badge badge-danger notifications-count">{{3}}</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" (click)="toggleNavbar()" type="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">
    <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': isCollapsed }">

    <ul class="navbar-nav float-right ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="javascript:void(0)">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold"href="javascript:void(0)">Policy</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-bd-logout">
          Logout
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

### Typescript

```
  public isCollapsed: boolean = false;

  toggleNavbar() {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand second part **the sidebar should push the content (Placeholder-Text) to the left.**

But for the first part for Sidebar try using Angular Material Navigation Option :

[Angular Material Sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)